# Capacitor value on supply grid

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current, capacitance, atmega328p

I am using ATmega328p TQFP for application described in schematic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNeakr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So there is plenty of load on output side (up to 500mA). I have used capacitor on main battery grid of 10uF/16v.

Working : Atmega328p will stay in sleep mode until interrupt is triggered. After wake up it will turn on the transistor(FMMT720 PNP) hence the whole circuitry will be powered up. During which it does some work and go back to sleep.

Problem : Sometimes (maybe once after 20 times) when interrupt is triggered nothing happens, like microcontroller is stuck somewhere. If now I provide ground on reset pin it will reset and then again things will work fine for few cycle until it stuck again.

So I tried different things and turns out that adding capacitor of 100uF/25V parallel to 10uF/16 never let this happen again.

So was this really issue of capacitance ? or charge ? If yes how you choose capacitor before in such case ?
If so why only few device shows this problem and not all ? and not every time ?
Does it has to do anything with varying transistor gain ?

I have checked all aspects I can from software side and I don't think there is issue in firmware.

Thank You.

Comment: Measure noise spikes on the supply while triggering the interrupt with and without the bigger capacitor. Compare the spike amplitude with the voltage specs of the CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The startup impedance of a boost converter is very low driving an uncharged output Cap.

Thus the ratio of source Cap ESR to load determines the glitch size on the input.

For this reason soft-start circuits are often used on boost converters or as you have done lower the input ESR by raising C. This is because all caps have different ESR values (low or general purpose) and the the ESR*C=T is constant within the dame family of capacitors. Typically it is <10us for low ESR types and 100~200 us for G.P. Types.

To measure glitches on any Vdd to gnd, use a small plastic AC coupling cap (low ESR) to 50 Ohms terminated at the DSO from 50 ohm coax. This can easily be done with a BNC T and a leaded resistor in the T socket if your DSO does not have this option.